# Handling "Your tests are loading..." Issue with Cypress After PayPal Login Redirection

Tags: javascript, testing, next.js, cypress

I'm encountering an issue with Cypress tests where, after successfully logging into the PayPal sandbox environment using cy.origin(), my tests don't proceed and instead display "Your tests are loading...". This occurs post-login redirection. I'm looking for insights or solutions to navigate this challenge.

Here's the relevant portion of my Cypress code:

```
Cypress.Commands.add('handlePayPalCredential', () => {
  cy.origin('https://www.sandbox.paypal.com', () => {
    cy.fixture('checkout/session').then(({ paypalEmail, paypalPassword }) => {
      cy.get('#email', { timeout: 10000 })
        .should('be.visible')
        .clear()
        .type(paypalEmail as string) // Using paypalEmail as is from the fixture

      cy.get('button[id="btnNext"]', { timeout: 10000 })
        .should('be.visible')
        .click()

      cy.get('#password', { timeout: 10000 })
        .should('be.visible')
        .clear()
        .type(paypalPassword as string) // Using paypalPassword as is from the fixture

      cy.get('button[id="btnLogin"]', { timeout: 10000 })
        .should('be.visible')
        .click()
    })
  })
})
```

After the login step, I'm redirected as expected, but Cypress seems to lose track of the test state, showing the message "Your tests are loading..." without any further progress.

What I've Tried:

1- Ensuring that all Cypress commands are correctly chained and asynchronous operations are properly handled.

2- Adding explicit waits and assertions to check for elements on the redirected page.

3- Checking for any console errors or warnings that might indicate what's happening post-redirection.

[image]

Questions:

Has anyone experienced a similar issue with Cypress tests hanging post-login, especially with cross-origin scenarios like PayPal?

Are there known workarounds or strategies to ensure Cypress can continue executing tests after a login redirection to a different domain?

Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance for your help!